# Node.js Error while installing npm install node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

I have to install node.js in my project for node modules while installing node modules its showing below error. How to rectifies this error.

Note: I ran npm run clean and delete my node modules folder and again ran npm install but did not work out.

If i run this project in with npm run build:client it's also showing

Missing script:build:Clinet

Let me know if add or delete or install.

Thanks....

```
"c:\Python\27\python.exe" i
    n the PATH
    gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: c:\Python\27\python.exe
    gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\wh
    ich\which.js:13:12)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\which\which.js:68
    :19)
    gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\which\which.js:80
    :29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\digitalframe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16

gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\digitalframe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\digitalframe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:
5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  c:\Python\27\python.exe { Error: not found: c:\Python\2
7\python.exe
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\wh
ich\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\which\which.js:68
:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\which\which.js:80
:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\digitalframe\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16

gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\digitalframe\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\digitalframe\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:
5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: c:\\Python\\27\\python.exe\n
    at getNotFoundError (C:\\digitalframe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\
n    at F (C:\\digitalframe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\
\digitalframe\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\digitalframe\\no
de_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\\digitalframe\\node_modules\\isexe\
\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\digitalframe\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n
   at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb could not find "c:\Python\27\python.exe". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "c:\Python\27\python.exe". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "c:\Python\27\python.exe", yo
u can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\no
de-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\digitalframe\node_modules\nod
e-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\digitalframe\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:
29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\digitalframe\\node_m
odules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--li
bsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\digitalframe\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\digitalframe\node_modu
les\yargs-parser\node_modules'
npm WARN  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\digitalframe\node_m
odules\yargs-parser\node_modules'
npm WARN   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat \'C:\\digitalfra
me\\node_modules\\yargs-parser\\node_modules\'',
npm WARN   errno: -4048,
npm WARN   code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN   syscall: 'lstat',
npm WARN   path: 'C:\\digitalframe\\node_modules\\yargs-parser\\node_modules' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.13.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message said: `Error: not found: c:\Python\27\python.exe`, You need `Python` with version `2.7` to build the node module.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you using node-gyp, you need to install required modules before you install node-gyp(python etc.). As I can see you are running it on windows machine, It is well known that this module is terrible on windows machine and barely ever works so I would suggest just ditching it and trying to find a better solution to your problem.